# Получить название текущей модели в админ шаблоне "change_list_result"

Tags: django, django-admin

Сталкнулся с необходимостью получить название модели которая отображается в шаблоне админки, для передачи этого названия в JS скрипт.

Как получить это название без изменения `django admin main view`? А изменяя только `change_list.html` или `change_list_result.html`. Мне нужно название внутри этих шаблонов как переменная `{{somename}}`.